# python: requests large.zip -> unzip -> fix -> filter ->gunzip

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I wrote a function to download a large zipfile 5-7gb from Iowa State MRMS data archive.

The zip files appear to be malformed and results in a `BadZipFileError` hence the `fix_badzip` function which calls a `subprocess` to repair the zip.

after the zip is repaired I have a function to filter the `ZipInfo` for select files.

The zip file contains several `grib2.gz` files, to which I use `gunzip` to extract

```
import uuid
import gzip
import shutil
import zipfile
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Literal, Iterable 

import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# these are enums that I defined that describe the iastate directory
# from .mmmpy import MRMSFeatures, MRMSRegions

GZ =  ".gz"
READ = "r"
WRITE_BINARY = "wb"

class IAStateZip(zipfile.ZipFile):
    def filterinfo(
        self,
        regions: list[str], # list[MRMSRegions],
        features: list[str], # list[MRMSFeatures],
    ) -> Iterable[zipfile.ZipInfo]:
        df = pd.DataFrame({"zipInfo": self.infolist(), "path": self.namelist()})
        df = df[df["path"].str.endswith(GZ)]
        df.loc[:, ["validTime", "region", "feature", "name"]] = np.vstack(
            df["path"].str.split("/")
        )
        region_mask = np.any(
            (np.array(regions)[:, np.newaxis] == df["region"].values).T, axis=1
        )
        feature_mask = np.any(
            (np.array(features)[:, np.newaxis] == df["feature"].values).T, axis=1
        )
        yield from df.loc[(region_mask & feature_mask), "zipInfo"]


def iastate_connect(start: datetime, out: Path, fix_zip: bool = True) -> Path:
    url = start.strftime("https://mrms.agron.iastate.edu/%Y/%m/%d/%Y%m%d%H.zip")
    print("downloading mrms data from:", url)
    _, filename = url.rsplit("/", maxsplit=1)
    file = out / filename
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        with file.open(WRITE_BINARY) as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
                fd.write(chunk)
    if fix_zip:
        fix_badzip(file)
    return file


def fix_badzip(corrupt: Path, in_place:bool=True):
    print("attempting to resolve zipfile")

    tmpfile = corrupt.parent / f"{uuid.uuid1()}.zip"

    subprocess.call(
        ["zip", "-FF", corrupt.as_posix(), f"--out={tmpfile.as_posix()}"],
        stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    )
    if in_place:
        corrupt.unlink()
        shutil.move(tmpfile, corrupt)



def main():
    data = Path.cwd().parent / "data"
    zfile = iastate_connect(
        datetime.fromisoformat("2022-06-01T12"), out=data
    )
    assert zfile.is_file()
    # open the zip file
    with IAStateZip(zfile) as zf:
        # filter the info inside of the zip
        for member in zf.filterinfo(regions=["CONUS"], features=["MergedReflectivityQC"]):
            # split the nested product directory
            directory, filename = member.filename.rsplit("/",maxsplit=1)
            # create a new file_path
            file_path = zfile.parent / directory
            if not file_path.exists():
                file_path.mkdir(parents=True)
            file = file_path / filename.removesuffix(GZ)
            # read the member from the zip file
            with zf.open(member,READ) as zref:
                # open a new file
                with file.open(WRITE_BINARY) as fdst:
                    # wrote the unziped & gunziped file to the new folder
                    fdst.write(gzip.decompress(zref.read()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It's tragic that their instance of Apache does not support HEAD or Range properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just delete these constants:

```
GZ =  ".gz"
READ = "r"
WRITE_BINARY = "wb"
```

They're pretty obvious.

These two parameters:

```
    regions: list[str], # list[MRMSRegions],
    features: list[str], # list[MRMSFeatures],
```

are probably better-represented as `set`s. I don't think that Pandas has much advantage here - you throw away most of your data immediately after construction so you should probably just have a plain filtration loop.

You should break this up:

```
url = start.strftime("https://mrms.agron.iastate.edu/%Y/%m/%d/%Y%m%d%H.zip")
```

into two separate variables, each using a format string:

```
filename = f'{start:%Y%m%d%H}.zip'
url = f'https://mrms.agron.iastate.edu/{start:%Y/%m/%d}/{filename}'
```

Then don't `rsplit` to get the filename.

Your chunk size should be much larger than 4k; try 4M.

You already use `shutil` elsewhere; you might as well `copyfileobj(r.raw, fd)` rather than `iter_content` in a loop.

Don't allow `shell=True` in your `subprocess` call.